# How to trigger a code on heroku

Tags: heroku, casperjs

I 've a casperjs code deployed on heroku, I want to trigger this code remotely (for now I have to login from the GUI -> console and type `casperjs index.js`).

I want to do that using a web service or from other heroku node app!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your node app to keep the process running, and listen on the provided $PORT environment variable for HTTP connections.

Then, set a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to define a web process type and scale that process to one dyno.

> heroku ps:scale web=1

You may want to follow this [getting started with node](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) article to get a better comprehension of how you can achieve this.